# How to validated a boost::python::object is a function signature with an argument

Tags: boost-python

How to validated a boost::python::object argument is a python function signature with an argument?

```html
void subscribe_py(boost::python::object callback){
        //check callback is a function signature


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Python does not provide a higher-level type to help perform introspection.  However, one can use the Python C-API's [`PyCallable_Check()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyCallable_Check) to check if a Python object is callable, and then use a Python introspection module, such as [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html), to determine the callable object's signature.  Boost.Python's interoperability between C++ and the Python makes this fairly seamless to use Python modules.

Here is an auxiliary function, `require_arity(fn, n)` that requires the expression `fn(a_0, a_1, ... a_n)` to be valid:

```cpp
/// @brief Given a Python object `fn` and an arity of `n`, requires
///        that the expression `fn(a_0, a_1, ..., a_2` to be valid.
///        Raise TypeError if `fn` is not callable and `ValueError`
///        if `fn` is callable, but has the wrong arity.
void require_arity(
  std::string name,
  boost::python::object fn,
  std::size_t arity)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  std::stringstream error_msg;
  error_msg << name << "() must take exactly " << arity << " arguments";

  // Throw if the callback is not callable.
  if (!PyCallable_Check(fn.ptr()))
  {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, error_msg.str().c_str());
    python::throw_error_already_set();
  }

  // Use the inspect module to extract the arg spec.
  // >>> import inspect
  auto inspect = python::import("inspect");
  // >>> args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(fn)
  auto arg_spec = inspect.attr("getargspec")(fn);
  python::object args = arg_spec[0];
  python::object varargs = arg_spec[1];
  python::object defaults = arg_spec[3];

  // Calculate the number of required arguments.
  auto args_count = args ? python::len(args) : 0;
  auto defaults_count = defaults ? python::len(defaults) : 0;

  // If the function is a bound method or a class method, then the
  // first argument (`self` or `cls`) will be implicitly provided.
  // >>> has_self = inspect.ismethod(fn) and fn.__self__ is not None
  if (static_cast<bool>(inspect.attr("ismethod")(fn))
      && fn.attr("__self__"))
  {
    --args_count;
  }

  // Require at least one argument.  The function should support
  // any of the following specs:
  //   >>> fn(a1)
  //   >>> fn(a1, a2=42)
  //   >>> fn(a1=42)
  //   >>> fn(*args)
  auto required_count = args_count - defaults_count;
  if (!(  (required_count == 1)                   // fn(a1), fn(a1, a2=42)
       || (args_count > 0 && required_count == 0) // fn(a1=42)
       || (varargs)                               // fn(*args)
    ))
 {
   PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, error_msg.str().c_str());
   python::throw_error_already_set();
 }
}
```

And its usage would be:

```python
void subscribe_py(boost::python::object callback)
{
  require_arity("callback", callback, 1); // callback(a1) is valid
  ...      
}
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8d5f23154e3e745) the usage:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <sstream>

/// @brief Given a Python object `fn` and an arity of `n`, requires
///        that the expression `fn(a_0, a_1, ..., a_2` to be valid.
///        Raise TypeError if `fn` is not callable and `ValueError`
///        if `fn` is callable, but has the wrong arity.
void require_arity(
  std::string name,
  boost::python::object fn,
  std::size_t arity)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  std::stringstream error_msg;
  error_msg << name << "() must take exactly " << arity << " arguments";

  // Throw if the callback is not callable.
  if (!PyCallable_Check(fn.ptr()))
  {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, error_msg.str().c_str());
    python::throw_error_already_set();
  }

  // Use the inspect module to extract the arg spec.
  // >>> import inspect
  auto inspect = python::import("inspect");
  // >>> args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(fn)
  auto arg_spec = inspect.attr("getargspec")(fn);
  python::object args = arg_spec[0];
  python::object varargs = arg_spec[1];
  python::object defaults = arg_spec[3];

  // Calculate the number of required arguments.
  auto args_count = args ? python::len(args) : 0;
  auto defaults_count = defaults ? python::len(defaults) : 0;

  // If the function is a bound method or a class method, then the
  // first argument (`self` or `cls`) will be implicitly provided.
  // >>> has_self = inspect.ismethod(fn) and fn.__self__ is not None
  if (static_cast<bool>(inspect.attr("ismethod")(fn))
      && fn.attr("__self__"))
  {
    --args_count;
  }

  // Require at least one argument.  The function should support
  // any of the following specs:
  //   >>> fn(a1)
  //   >>> fn(a1, a2=42)
  //   >>> fn(a1=42)
  //   >>> fn(*args)
  auto required_count = args_count - defaults_count;
  if (!(  (required_count == 1)                   // fn(a1), fn(a1, a2=42)
       || (args_count > 0 && required_count == 0) // fn(a1=42)
       || (varargs)                               // fn(*args)
    ))
 {
   PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, error_msg.str().c_str());
   python::throw_error_already_set();
 }
}

void perform(
  boost::python::object callback,
  boost::python::object arg1)
{
  require_arity("callback", callback, 1);
  callback(arg1);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("perform", &perform);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> def test(fn, a1, expect=None):
...     try:
...         example.perform(fn, a1)
...         assert(expect is None)
...     except Exception as e:
...         assert(isinstance(e, expect))
... 
>>> test(lambda x: 42, None)
>>> test(lambda x, y=2: 42, None)
>>> test(lambda x=1, y=2: 42, None)
>>> test(lambda *args: None, None)
>>> test(lambda: 42, None, ValueError)
>>> test(lambda x, y: 42, None, ValueError)
>>> 
>>> class Mock:
...     def method_no_arg(self): pass
...     def method_with_arg(self, x): pass
...     def method_default_arg(self, x=1): pass
...     @classmethod
...     def cls_no_arg(cls): pass
...     @classmethod
...     def cls_with_arg(cls, x): pass
...     @classmethod
...     def cls_with_default_arg(cls, x=1): pass
... 
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> test(Mock.method_no_arg, mock)
>>> test(mock.method_no_arg, mock, ValueError)
>>> test(Mock.method_with_arg, mock, ValueError)
>>> test(mock.method_with_arg, mock)
>>> test(Mock.method_default_arg, mock)
>>> test(mock.method_default_arg, mock)
>>> test(Mock.cls_no_arg, mock, ValueError)
>>> test(mock.cls_no_arg, mock, ValueError)
>>> test(Mock.cls_with_arg, mock)
>>> test(mock.cls_with_arg, mock)
>>> test(Mock.cls_with_default_arg, mock)
>>> test(mock.cls_with_default_arg, mock)
```

Strict checking of function types can be argued as being non-Pythonic and can become complicated due to the various types of callables (bound-method, unbound method, classmethod, function, etc).  Before applying strict type checking, it may be worth assessing if strict type checking is required, or if alternatives checks, such as [Abstract Base Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/), would be sufficient.  For instance, if the `callback` functor will be invoked within a Python thread, then it may be worth not performing type checking, and allow the Python exception to be raised when invoked.  On the other hand, if the `callback` functor will be invoked from within a non-Python thread, then type checking within the initiating function can allow one to throw an exception within the calling Python thread.

Comment: You're not using the `arity` parameter in your examples, so you only check for 1 argument?